# What is the another use of de Bruijn graphs in bioinformatics except DNA assembly?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-sequencing, rna-sequencing

I implemented own generic de Bruijn graph, which I use for DNA assembly (alphabet: A, C, G, T). I try to find purpose of de Bruijn graph for another bioinformatics problems, if some exists. I want use/modify my implementation to solve this.
Are there another problems in bioinformatics which we can solve with de Bruijn graphs?

I found only RNA assembly, which is similar to DNA assembly.